# how to display image from webroot folder using the image pathname in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

Hai i am new to the cakephp.I have create one sample form having two fields name and image file.I was able to save image name and uername in database table and save the image in webroot folder.Now i want to retrieve image using particular id.How can i retrieve the image from the webroot folder using the particular user id?.Please help me to improve my knowledge in cakephp.

Add.ctp

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>  
'add','type' => 'file','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file')); 
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {
 public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add','retrieve');

}

public function retrieve() 
{
  $this->loadModel('User');

$ret = $this->User->find('all');
    $this->set('retrieve', $ret);

}
public function add()
{

       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
    $this->loadModel('User');
 $id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];

    $pathname = $this->request->data['User']['image']['tmp_name'];       
    $filename = $this->request->data['User']['image']['name'];

    $this->request->data['User']['image'] = $filename;
     if($this->User->save($this->request->data))
 {
        move_uploaded_file($pathname,  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cakephp_image  
 /app/webroot/files/' . $filename);
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Image has been saved'));
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>  
'retrieve'));   
   } 
else 
{
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The Image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
 }
}
}


 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code here? without that it will be like building castle's in the year. A short answer to your question will be that first retrieve the image id from database then use it like this

```
 <img src="<?php echo Router::url('/', true).'/'.$image_name'; //image name from database  ?>"></img>
```

Now the $image_name is what you will have to store in database along with username so whenyou have a query like

```
  Select * FROM `foo` where username="'.$_POST['username'].'"
```

It will return the image name as well which you can use to fetch the image from your root folder

Comment: When you have a query like that, then you have a nice SQL injection vulnerability...

Comment: It was not for getting it copy pasted into his script. It was for demonstration. If you are going to use it , i will have no concerns :D, for security use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])